# Is there a way to distribute your Chrome app with Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome app, and I'm wondering if there is a way to offer customers a single downloadable package that will provide both Chrome (the browser) and my app.

You sometimes see this with Java and Adobe AIR apps.  You can either download just the app (if you already have the JVM or AIR, respectively), or you can download a package that includes the app plus the runtime.

In this case, Chrome is the runtime. Is there a way to offer a single download that will install Chrome along with my app? I can offer that as an option for users who do not already have Chrome installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that is being actively developed now. The bug to follow is https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341353, but there isn't much visible there as it is being developed in an internal repository at Google.

Comment: Disappointed that it's not already possible--but glad to see that it's being actively developed now! I will be watching this bug to see how this is addressed. The installation experience is a major factor in a consumer app's adoption. It needs to be easy and seamless.

Comment: Update: as of today, the bug "Fix is Verified on Windows7 with Latest Dev: 40.0.2209.0 (Official Build)." So, I'm guessing we'll see it released in a stable Chrome build Q1 2015?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what that message was about. The app installer is being worked on actively, and we're making solid progress, but it isn't quite ready yet.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it was accidentally posted to the wrong bug. I can't say it's never happened to me.